# Quartz Scheduler - Is the job correctly scheduled?

Tags: java, twilio, quartz-scheduler

**Fully Updated Code**

---

I am using Twilio to implement a text reminder to be send 3 days before an appointment. I have implemented it in my back-end (java). I have added a few visits into the database that should trigger a job to be scheduled but I am unsure how to check if the job has been scheduled to send a message?

I know the visit is being added to the database since I can check that, so `scheduleJob(visit);` should be scheduling a text to send, but I am not sure.

VisitController.java

```
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addVisit(@RequestBody Visit visit){
        Result<Visit> result = service.add(visit);
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            scheduleJob(visit);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result.getPayload(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return ErrorResponse.build(result);
    }

private void scheduleJob(Visit visit) {
        String visitId = String.valueOf(visit.getVisitId());

        ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        LocalDate date = visit.getVisitDate().minusDays(3);
        Date finalDate = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(defaultZoneId).plusHours(16).toInstant());

        JobDetail job =
                newJob(VisitScheduler.class).withIdentity("Appointment_J_" + visitId)
                        .usingJobData("visitId", visitId).build();

        Trigger trigger =
                newTrigger().withIdentity("Appointment_T_" + visitId).startAt(finalDate).build();

        try {
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to schedule the Job");
        }
    }
```

VisitScheduler.java

```
public class VisitScheduler implements Job {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VisitScheduler.class);

    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "account sid";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "auth token";
    public static final String TWILIO_NUMBER = "twilio number";
    public static final String TO_NUMBER= "number to send messages to";

    private final VisitRepository repository;
    public VisitScheduler(VisitRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {

        VisitService service = new VisitService(repository);

        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

        int visitId = Integer.parseInt(dataMap.getString("visitId"));

        Visit visit = service.findByVisitId(visitId);
        if (visit != null) {
            String date = String.valueOf(visit.getVisitDate());
            String time = String.valueOf(visit.getVisitTime());
            String messageBody = "This is a reminder about your visit at " + time + " on " + date + " See you then!";

            try {
                Message message = Message
                        .creator(new PhoneNumber(TO_NUMBER), new PhoneNumber(TWILIO_NUMBER), messageBody)
                        .create();
                System.out.println("Message sent! Message SID: " + message.getSid());
            } catch(TwilioException ex) {
                logger.error("An exception occurred trying to send the message \"{}\" to {}." +
                        " \nTwilio returned: {} \n", messageBody, TO_NUMBER, ex.getMessage());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this correct? int visitId = dataMap.getInt("visitId"); should it no use getString?

Comment: @NigelSavage I've updated my code to use getString, but I need to parse it to an int since service.findByVisitId takes an int

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In this line you store the job data:

```java
JobDetail job = newJob(VisitScheduler.class).withIdentity("Appointment_J_" + visitId)
                .usingJobData("appointmentId", visitId).build();
```

You set the `"appointmentId"` to `visitId`.

In `VisitScheduler` you then try to get the `visitId` with:

```java
int visitId = Integer.parseInt(dataMap.getString("visitId"));
```

Should this be `"appointmentId"` to match the field you set earlier?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did not catch that. I have updated my code to reflect that change

Comment: Did that fix it? What is actually going wrong?

Comment: there were a few other issues as well with my repo & service and formatting of the date, but it is now working!